# HTML5 Validation Error - stuck in an 'invalid' loop

Tags: php, html

Probably very simple this one, but it's still troubling me.

I have a form, embedded in php, which I need to perform validation on.

An example of one of the fields is:

```
Server 1:
</td>
<td>
    <input name='1_server[1]' value='$defaultserver1' id='server1' required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter server name/IP Address for this connection')">
</td>
</tr>
```

...as per the above, I have a default value that can be set/inserted when the page loads, but I mainly want to cater for if this isn't set.

If you delete the field, the validation works fine.  The problem is, retyping in the field still persist to show the invalid warning.

**To Summarise:**

If field is empty, and the form submit button is clicked, validation warning shows.  You can't, however, fill in the form after this point, as it seems to get 'stuck' in think that the field is 'invalid', even if you complete it.

Can anyone help?  I've no doubt I'm being soft...

**Edit:**  Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/v03sb4hq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved this.

setting the      `oninvalid="setCustomValidity('please fill in')"` flag will, on invalid input, set the Validity to a fixed state of 'invalid'.

To counter-act this, I need to state a cleared flag when an input is detected on the same field, i.e. `oninput="setCustomValidity('')"`

So, my revised code is now...

`<input name='1_server[1]' value='$defaultserver1' id='server1' required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter server name/IP Address for this connection')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"`>

**Fiddle updated here:**   https://jsfiddle.net/v03sb4hq/2/

Answer (score -1):

Is `$defaultserver1` a php variable? In that case you'd have to echo it within the HTML code, I think.

```
<input name='1_server[1]' value='<?php echo $defaultserver1;?>' id='server1' required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter server name/IP Address for this connection')">
```

Comment: Yes, but I took that out as it wasn't relevant to the question/issue

Comment: For the sake of clarifying,

     value='$defaultserver1'

works fine within an echo

Comment: Just in case you are using safari, oninvalid does not seem to be supported.

Comment: No, Chrome.  OnInvalid is working, as per the question, but it's stuck in an 'invalid' state.

Comment: There seems to be no mistake in the code that you shared. I even checked in an online editor and it's showing the response you expected. Is your html syntax correct? For the rest of the code? And are you positive you're echoing the variable in php? I'm sorry mate. Your code works fine on my end.

Comment: It's not related to the PHP aspect.

The oninvalid is causing the issue, but for no apparent reason..

Comment: Ok correction. It doesn't work fine on my end. I don't know why, but try using `alert` instead of `setCustomValidity` . Worked for me!

Comment: Because I want to work out a correction solution based on HTML5 (with a flag/indicator), not a JS popup bodge

Comment: use `this.setCustomValidity(this.willValidate?'':'Please enter server name/IP Address for this connection')` instead. Apparently you need to set a blank string `''` to clear the invalid flag. It's the problem with the `setCustomValidity()` method, and not with your code.